# Display message if combobox value is "this" (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to display a message to the user if the user selects a specific value in a combobox. I have written some code of it but doesn't seem to work. Please help.

Thank you.

here is the code I have produced

```
Private Sub repaired1_TextUpdate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles repaired1.TextUpdate
    If repaired1.Text = ("Fixed") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please generate ID", "No Entry", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        With txtid
            .Focus()
            .SelectAll()
            Me.refreshdata()
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Current Code

```
Private Sub repaired1_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles repaired1.SelectedValueChanged
    If repaired1.SelectedItem.ToString.Equals("Fixed") Then
        MsgBox("Remember to log in date fixed ")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Which bit doesn't seem to work? What error are you seeing or what result are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

```
if repaired1.selecteditem.tostring.equals("Fixed") Then
```

You may want to check that you are triggering your event on the right change also.

Have a look at 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_combobox.htm

Try...

```
   Private Sub repaired1_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles repaired1.SelectedValueChanged
    MsgBox("Clicked " & repaired1.SelectedItem.ToString)
End Sub
```

See what it thinks you've selected.

Comment: what event would I need to use, I have tried selectedvaluedchanged but it doesn't work.

Comment: Private Sub repaired1_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles repaired1.SelectedValueChanged

Comment: just tried but doesn't seem to have any message box alert when I select "Fixed" from combo box.

Comment: I have changed the code which I have edited in post, but no luck getting it to work.

Comment: it works, but there is a slight problem, the combo box has 2 values (Fixed and pending) I only want "Fixed" to display message, if pending is selected no message box is needed, at the moment message box pops up for every both values selected.

Comment: This shows that the sub is being called correctly, now you just need to write the if statement that matches exactly what it says in the box (case sensitive)

Comment: i have edited the code shown above but doesn't work.

Comment: if you can get the vb solution to me I will have a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71759/discussion-between-peterp-and-user3562155).

Comment: do you want me to give you the entire vb source code?